# How to tell if (2d) points A B C form are clockwise or anticlockwise?

Tags: trigonometry

I have three different 2d points, A, B and C.

A is at the origin.

How can I tell whether the points make a clockwise or widdershins triangle?

I'd really like to avoid using tan if possible.  (I'm programming a microcontroller.)  I already have implementations of sine and cosine, so using those is no trouble.

Comment: By cw/ccw is it with respect to a specific line of the triangle? Like, is $AB$ a "fixed" reference?

Comment: Whether the points A B C are clockwise when drawn in their positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the sign of the cross product of the vectors A->B and A->C.